# Deleting a file from server on button click in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm not well versed in this framework so I need some help here. In a view I want to add a link or a button on clicking which a certain file gets deleted from the server. 
I've added this method to the controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult DeleteFile(string path)
    {
        if ((System.IO.File.Exists(path)))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Deletion of file failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Seemed straightforward, though I'm not sure about the `return View();`. Now in the view, I need a form, because the path to the file that should be deleted needs to be posted to the controller, is that correct? This is what I got so far, mimicked from other code in the project:

```
@Html.BeginForm("DeleteFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "delete-attachment-form" })
    {

        @Html.Hidden("path", path)
    }
```

`path` is a JavaScript variable containing the server path to the file that needs to be deleted. If I'm on the right track here, how do I add a button or a link to click on that will send the form?

Comment: Should just be able to add a submit button: `<input type="submit" name="submit" />`

Comment: Add a submit button to your form and be sure to mark your action with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: How are you using the `path` javascript variable exactly?  The server will render your HTML from `@Html.Hidden` before javascript executes.

Comment: @stephen.vakil good point, I misspoke though, it's actually a C# variable inside the razor block.

Comment: @Ksib if this were an answer I'd accept it. Simple and it works.

Comment: @speedymcs I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be able to add a submit button:

`<input type="submit" name="submit" />`

Answer (score 1):

You should have a form and a button like this

`@Html.BeginForm("Controller", "DeleteFile", new {Path= filePath},FormMethod.Post)
{
//Button
}`

Or using Ajax and Jquery

var values = $(this).serialize();

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "url?path="+path.tostring(),
      data: values ,
      success: function(response) { //update view }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form you can add a button and then handle the button click in JavaScript.

```
@Html.BeginForm("DeleteFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "delete-attachment-form" })
{
    @Html.Hidden("path", path)
    <button id="delete-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete
    </button>
}
```

Then the `<script type="text/javascript">` block:

```
$(function () {
    $('#delete-btn').click(function () {
        var query = $('#delete-attachment-form');
        var form = query[0];
        var toPost = query.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            data: toPost,
            success: function (result) {
                // display result
            },
            error: function () {
                // handle error
            }
        })            
    });
});
```

Also, [this is](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-details-and-delete-methods) a good tutorial on deleting in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Thanks. But is there a reason that adding that chunk of jQuery code instead of just the line `<input type="submit" name="submit" />` as proposed in the comments? Seems much simpler

Comment: Gives you access to Ajax success/error functions so you can adjust the UI dynamically.